# Macro to obtain current namespace and function name (but not full signature)?

Tags: c++, boost, macros

Is there a C++ macro that obtains the current namespace and function name? Example:

```
namespace foo {
  namespace bar {
    void baz(int i, double d) {
      std::cout << MACRO << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

would print `foo::bar::baz`. I know of `__FUNCTION__` but it doesn't give the namespace. And `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION` gives the whole signature, incl. arguments and return type:

```
void foo::bar::baz(int, double)
```

Maybe, is it possible to write a macro that extracts the namespace and function name from `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`?

I want that for logging purposes, to get a logging string like

```
foo::bar::baz -- blah logging message blah
```

Comment: I don't think there is any platform independent way to get the full signature of the function. However, why can't you use the combo of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` ? It will give you almost the same effect; moreover that is faster to locate in your code from the logs compared to searching a function!

Comment: @iammilind: Actually, I want to use the macro content as the logger name in log4cxx. Those logger names are hierarchical and you can set different log levels for different namespaces, etc. So what I really do is something like `log4cxx::LoggerPtr logger(log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("foo.bar.baz")); LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "blah logging message blah");` The MACRO should fill in the `foo.bar.baz` part. I didn't want to make it that complicated in my post.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, it's not possible (not portably). However from the full signature you can *extract* those arguments. Of course it requires parsing said signature... which is not so easy :x

Here is the function I use at the moment:

```
// What we want to consume:
//  void
//  signed short
//  unsigned int
//  Test::Bar<T, N>
//
static char const* consumeType(char const* const begin, char const* const end){
  static StringRef const Signed("signed");
  static StringRef const Unsigned("unsigned");

  char const* it = begin;

  if (startsWith(it, Signed)) { it += Signed.size() + 1; }
  else if (startsWith(it, Unsigned)) { it += Unsigned.size() + 1; }

  // jump over the return type
  size_t templateNest = 0;
  while (it != end) {
    if (*it == ' ' and templateNest == 0) { break; }
    if (*it == '<') { ++templateNest; }
    if (*it == '>' and templateNest > 0) { --templateNest; }

    ++it;
  }

  return it;
} // consumeType

//
// \param signature: signature as returned by __func___ on gcc
// \return: full name, included namespace qualifier and class (if any)
//
// void Test::Bar<T, N>::parameterized(U) const
//   [with unsigned int O = 4u, U = Test::Foo,
//    T = Test::Foo, unsigned int N = 3u]
//    -> Test::Bar<T, N>::parameterized
//
StringRef parseFunctionName(StringRef const signature) {
  char const* begin = signature.begin();
  char const* end = signature.end();

  // Jump over the return type
  begin = consumeType(begin, end);
  if (begin == end) { return signature; }

  // skip the space right after the return type
  ++begin;
  if (begin == end) { return signature; }

  // if we encounter a '(' then it means that we return a function,
  // and we once again need to jump over the return type
  if (*begin == '(') {
    begin = consumeType(++begin, end);

    // skip the space
    ++begin;
    if (begin == end) { return signature; }
  }

  // and finally, we got the beginning, and we need to get the end, which is
  // the first opening '('
  char const* e = std::find(begin, end, '(');
  return StringRef(begin, e - begin);
} // parseFunctionName
```

And its accompagnying tests:

```
#define UT_FUNCTION_CHECK(Signature_, Name_) \
  UT_CHECK(parseFunctionName(StringRef(Signature_)) == Name_);

void Function() {
  // Regular functions
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("int main()", "main")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("int foo(int, double)", "foo")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("unsigned int foo(int, double)", "foo")

  // Templates
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("unsigned int Test::Bar<T, N>::print() const"
                    " [with T = Test::Foo, unsigned int N = 3u]",
                    "Test::Bar<T, N>::print")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("Test::Bar<T, N> Test::Bar<T, N>::print() const"
                    " [with T = Test::Foo, unsigned int N = 3u]",
                    "Test::Bar<T, N>::print")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("void Test::Bar<T, N>::parameterized(U) const"
                    " [with unsigned int O = 4u, U = Test::Foo,"
                    " T = Test::Foo, unsigned int N = 3u]",
                    "Test::Bar<T, N>::parameterized")

  // Functions returning functions
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("void (* Test::Foo::func() const)()",
                    "Test::Foo::func")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("void (Test::Foo::* Test::Foo::method() const)(int)volatile",
                    "Test::Foo::method")
  UT_FUNCTION_CHECK("void (Test::Foo::* Test::Foo::super())"
                    "(void (Test::Foo::*)(int)volatile)const",
                    "Test::Foo::super")
  } // Function
```

It works in combination with gcc's `__func__` macro.

The `StringRef` class is similar to [`llvm::StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/StringRef_8h.html).

I think it should cover your needs if you can afford the extra parsing. It's quite fast: no backtracking and no dynamic allocation, so should not be an issue (especially compared to writing to a file...).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to make it compile. How is `consumeType` defined?

Comment: @Frank: I don't quite understand the question... it's defined as written in the answer ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. It seems that `__func__` has been standardized to not contain the full name and signature, and that you now need to use GCC's `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. 
C++20 has / will have a nonmacro solution with `std::source_location::function_name`