# How to get string for current namespace in Macro

Tags: c++, namespaces, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to put namespace prefix in macros. I.e.

```
#define MYMACRO(x) ....##x

namespace A {
  namespace B {
    MYMACRO(C);
  }
}
```

and MYMACRO must return - A::B::C?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124856/macro-to-obtain-current-namespace-and-function-name-but-not-full-signature

Comment: @Daniele: No, that is a different scope.

Comment: `I need to put namespace prefix in macros` No, you don't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't work. Namespaces are recognized by the compiler, which runs only after the preprocessor.

Comment: That's the right answer. And it might lead to a solution: If you need something to be seen by the preprocessor, put it there. Before namespace A, put a #define OUTERNAMESPACE A, before B define INNERNAMESPACE B. How that would be better than just writing it manually I don't know.

Comment: @starmole: Well, it would be called "writing it manually twice" :)